# Awkward/wrong PostgreSQL foreign-key definition

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, pg-dump

As a database developer, I experienced this notice when I tried to make a data-only dump a PostgreSQL(10.1) database 'tlesson'.

Notice =>

```
  pg_dump: NOTICE: there are circular foreign-key constraints on this table:
  pg_dump: members
```

Dump command =>

```
  $ pg_dump -U postgres -d translesson -a
```

A 'tlesson' table 'members' constraint =>

```
  ALTER TABLE ONLY members
    ADD CONSTRAINT friend_fk FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES members(member_id);
```

- That is, 'friend_id' column refers own table's primary key as the foreign-key.

Should I drop the 'friend_fk' constraint to remove the notice I'm having?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always drop the entire database then this isn't a problem, because the generated SQL (or pg_restore) will enable (create) foreign keys only after all the data was loaded, so there is no problem in that case.

However if you only dump a single table without the FKs then, importing is only going to work if you manually drop the FK before restoring, then re-create it afterwards.

The reason is that it's nearly impossible to generate INSERT statements in the correct order if you have circular references